# MVC4 Deployment Issues on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a strange issue with Azure!

I just recently upgraded my azure deployed site from **MVC3 to MVC4**. I did this by creating a brand new MVC4 project which uses only Nuget packages so should be "bin deployable"? I copied only the essential sections across from my Web.config in the root and in the Views folder.

Everything works fine locally, but after deploying to Azure I find that the role is stuck in "Busy" but the website works! It also spontaneously recycles the instance (im guessing due to its busy status).

I added Intellitrace to the deployment, and it's complaining that this reference does not exist:

Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:

-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0'

I have no idea why it is trying to load an MVC Version 3 reference in a 4 project. I've searched the Web.configs for any references to 3.0.0.0 and the references for the project seem fine.

Please help! Are there any extra debugging steps i can take?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Does your project by chance include MVCMailer? https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/42

Comment: I have had a similar issue regarding the role constantly being recycled (and re-created) due to a missing DLL, in my case it was one of the Microsoft.ReportViewer assemblies. Opening a remote desktop session to the instance, I could see that the CPU was maxing out. IntelliTrace also pointed out the problem in my case. I was missing the actual DLL in the deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the same question as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/9c2f6b62-185d-4a38-8bb5-eda1917604d9. As pointed out in the other thread:

Have you configured assembly redirection? If you create a new Windows Azure project with a MVC 4 web role (now supported in SDK 1.7), you will see the following redirection:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Apologies for the double post. It was super urgent - In the end, i switched to the new Azure Websites service which seems to be running things very smoothly. +1 for PaaS.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and binding redirect doesn't seem to do anything :-(

Comment: @JoeS I wouldn't apologize for the double post [it is on different forums after all :) ]. I think it's good to find different sources of answers, make sure that both ones have links to each other though is my tip :)

Comment: @Craig, I had the same issue as you. In addition on the assembly binding redirect, fixed this by making the <configSections> of web.config have the following: https://gist.github.com/3866047

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have copy local set to true for the System.Web.Mvc reference so its being copied up in your deployment package?

Comment: I do indeed, my System.Web.Mvc reference points to the nuget package: <Solution>\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20505.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll

And copy-local is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem upload my project to Azure,
In addition I did your recommends respectively ,

So It was necessary to create the my project a startup task and after that I generated script for this startup task . Check your hosted service and 
I hosted service is windows Server R2 so I changed my ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg file .The **OsFamily** attribute is changed “**1**” to “**2**”.

You can find the more info in this link : [Windows Azure Startup Tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitolo/archive/2013/01/03/windows-azure-startup-tasks.aspx) , It is written in Italian but you can translate it to English.